How do I calculate the Range of Performance of a HP Rocket Motor due to Temperature?
I'm working in a team building a HP rocket with a J-motor, the Contrail J800-HP Hybrid Motor, to be specific. It is fuelled by a solid plastic fuel and nitrous oxide as a liquid oxidiser. We're writing up our DDID and trying to add information on the motor's range of performance due to temperature in our propulsion section. I've got a thrust curve for it online, however, I'd like to find its performance range, but I'm new to rocketry so I really don't know where I'd start. I was wondering if I can run a simulation on OpenRocket for it and plot it but I couldn't do that for some reason.
Definitely a beginner here, so I'd appreciate detailed and even dumbed down answers.
https://www.thrustcurve.org/simfiles/5f4294d20002e90000000322/ - here's a link to the thrust curve online
I'll also insert an image of the actual thrust curve:


You should know that questions regarding physical experiments are against the site rules. If you edit your question to remove any mention of testing etc. it will avoid getting closed by the site moderation.

The second thing you should know is that the initial temperature of a solid rocket motor will affect its performance, but likely in a very small way. My intuition is that the burn rate will see a small increase if the motor is warmer. This is related to the activation energy required in the preheat zone of the propellant for ignition being a specific and finite value. If the initial temperature of the propellant is higher, then less heat transfer is required to increase its temperature to the ignition point, yielding faster burn rates. You should try to find research papers on the topic.
